# how to add current active user as foreign key to the task model in django 3?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a task to do web app using django 3,
I have two models one is UserCustom and other is UserTask in which each corresponding active user can add task.
I am getting the entry details through a "model form".
For adding the task user need to be login.
But mentioning UserCustom as foriegn key in UserTask model, creates a combo (dropdown) box on the "AddTask.html" page with all the registered users.

How can i autimatically add current active user as foreign key in UserTask model ?

Below are the codes

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
# Create your models here.

class UserCustom(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    profile_pic=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics',blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username   #user os object defined above

class UserTask(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserCustom,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    label=models.CharField(max_length=264)
    date=models.DateField()
    status=models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.label)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.fields import DateField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from taskApp.models import UserCustom,UserTask
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model=User
        fields=('username','email','password')

class UserCustomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=UserCustom
        fields=('profile_pic',)

class UserTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date=DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD', 'required': 'required'}))
    class Meta():
        model=UserTask
        fields=('author','label','status','date')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from taskApp.forms import UserForm,UserCustomForm,UserTaskForm

#below libraries required for login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'taskApp/index.html')

@login_required
def add_task(request):
    #return HttpResponse("You are logged in, Nice!")
    added=False
    if request.method == "POST":
        task_form=UserTaskForm(data=request.POST)
        if task_form.is_valid():

            task=task_form.save()
            #task.user=user
            task.save()

            added=True

        else:
            print(task_form.errors)


    else: #no request=POST yet
        task_form=UserTaskForm()

    return render(request,'taskApp/task.html',{'added':added,'task_form':task_form})


@login_required
def user_logout(request):  #only login users can logout
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))


def register(request):

    registered=False

    if request.method == "POST":

        user_form=UserCustomForm(data=request.POST)
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            #grabbing user form ,saving to DB and hashing the password and then saving the changes
            user=user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile=profile_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user=user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic=request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile.save()

            registered=True

        else:
            print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

    else: #no request=POST yet
        user_form=UserCustomForm()
        profile_form=UserProfileInfoForm()

    return render(request,'taskApp/registration.html',
                            {'user_form':user_form,
                            'profile_form':profile_form,
                            'registered':registered })



def user_login(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')  #name of element
        password=request.POST.get('password')

        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index')) #redirect to home page
            else:
                return HttpResponse("ACCOUNT NOT ACTIVE")

        else:
            print("Someone tried to login and failed!")
            print("Username: {} and password {}".format(username,password))
            return HttpResponse("invalid login details supllied!")

    else:
        return render(request,'taskApp/login.html',{})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the current user with `request.user`.

```
...
 if request.method == "POST":
    task_form=UserTaskForm(data=request.POST)
    if task_form.is_valid():

        task=task_form.save(commit=False)
        task.author= request.user
        task.save()

        added=True
...
```

Comment: Its still throwing **ValueError at /taskApp/addTaskHandle/
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: ashish>>": "UserTask.author" must be a "UserCustom" instance.
Request Method: POST**     Is my way of specifying foreign key in models.py is correct? I have not added any extra statement like AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py as they were for Older django versions..    @kamilyrb

Comment: Its done now, i had to change the foreign Key to 'Users' in models.py.   Thanks.

Comment: Is it okey now?

Comment: Yes its working, further i need to ask how to fetch the task data from UserTask model defined above,  for the particular user ?  I am sending the context dictionary "task_form" from views.py to "task.html" ,do i need to create and send any other object from view.py ?

Comment: Normally, you can get tasks of specicific user with `UserTask.objects.filter(author=request.user)`. Do you need to fetching user's task in html file or python side?

Comment: Thanks, its done I was fetching the data from views.py onto the other HTML page (namely myTasks.html ).